# Unable To Read A CSV File Using Pandas

Tags: pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

PATH = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\test.csv"
pd.read_csv(PATH)

I read a hell lot of things. Still I can't know what is happening right here.
Why can't I read a file? I am using Windows 10 and Jupyter Notebok.

**FileNotFoundError: File b'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\test.csv' does not exist**

Comment: \ backslash in python strings can be a pain in the a**. Read about it and you will understand what is wrong. The quickest fix is by making the string a raw string: `PATH = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\test.csv"` (I added an r)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jupyter, there are couple ways to go about this.

Option 1.

Upload the `.csv` to the directory in which your `.ipynb` is.

[image: jupyter]

The upload button is on the far right. If you do that then you don't have to write out the whole path of the file. `df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")` should work.

Option 2.

Put an `r` in front of the path. Python reads strings with `\` as escape characters, so doesn't understand what you're trying to do.

Solution --> `path = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\test.csv"`

Answer (score -1):

Q:  Unable To Read A CSV File Using Pandas
PATH = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\test.csv"

A:
pandas needs a full path when using CSV and does not accept certain characters in the path

not working:  like \1 and \v  \t \r ....

df= pd.read_csv('G:\Mijn Drive\Python_projects\SIMPEL_01\1games.csv')
df= pd.read_csv('G:\Mijn Drive\Python_projects\SIMPEL_01\vgames.csv')

working:
df= pd.read_csv('G:\Mijn Drive\Python_projects\SIMPEL_01\games.csv')